# ASP.NET MVC Populating a DropdownList with foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a scaffolded Create view for an entry in my database, which contains a DropdownList containing ExamIDs.
The idea here is to create a new record in the Registrations table in the DB, where a Registration contains a GUID for an Exam (ExamID).
The list is currently populated with GUIDs from the Exams.

The Exams themselves don't have a name but are linked to a Course (which does have a name) in another table through a foreign key in the DB (CourseID).

What I need to have is a list populated with the names of the Courses associated with the Exam, but still parses the correct ExamID when you create the new record.

Since I'm a novice at C#/ASP.NET, I've been mucking about with ViewBags and lambda expressions, none of which worked. At one point I thought I had it by making a new ViewBar for Courses and parsing that to the DropdownList but naturally that caused a DB error because it wanted to save the CourseID from one table as ExamID from another, in a table in which CourseID is not a key.

The Controller:

```
    // GET: Registrations/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ExamId = new SelectList(db.Exams, "Id", "Id");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Registrations/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,ExamId,StudentId,Deleted,TimeStamp")] Registration registration)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            registration.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            registration.StudentId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            registration.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            db.Registrations.Add(registration);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.StudentId = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "Firstname", registration.StudentId);
        ViewBag.ExamId = new SelectList(db.Exams, "Id", "Name", registration.ExamId);
        return View(registration);
    }
```

The View:

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Kies een tentamen</h4>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExamId, "Vak", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ExamId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExamId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Schrijf in"  class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The bit I'm after is showing a linked Course Name instead of the GUID from ExamID in the view.

Comment: you say Exam is linked to Course by foreign key, is this a one to many, many to many, one to one?

Comment: @JamieD77 it's a Course 1---* Exam relation.

Comment: how will you know which exam you're taking if it's a 1 to many.. unless every course has only one exam, you would just see the same course name multiple times in your dropdown

Comment: did you try using the code that was auto generated for you, that you seem to have overridden? `ViewBag.ExamId = new SelectList(db.Exams, "Id", "Name", registration.ExamId);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a Course navigation on your Exam class, try this:

```
private SelectList GetExamList()
{
    return db.Exams
      .Select(e => new SelectListItem {
         Value = e.Id, 
         Text = e.Course.Name })
     .ToList();
}
```

Change to:

```
ViewBag.ExamId = GetExamList();
```

Comment: Thanks so much!
Took some fiddling but it eventually worked.
Had to change the function to:
`private List<SelectListItem> GetExamList()`

and the ViewBag to:
`ViewBag.ExamList = new SelectList(GetExamList(), "Value", "Text");`

and in the view:
`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ExamId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ExamList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

Because i got endless data type errors otherwise, but this was ultimately the right answer!